# Can i use nested arrays in const in PHP

Tags: php, constants

I know that const can take an array, but I want to have a constant which contains nested arrays. Is this possible?

```
const DAYS_OFF = array(
  'holidays' => array(
    'newYear' => '1 January'
  )
)
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing with it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use nested arrays in constants. An array is an array, regardless of depth:

```
const DAYS_OFF = array(
  'holidays' => array(
    'newYear' => '1 January'
  )
);

print_r(DAYS_OFF);
```

returns:

```
Array
(
    [holidays] => Array
        (
            [newYear] => 1 January
        )

)

echo DAYS_OFF['holidays']['newYear'];
```

returns

> 1 January

Comment: Does not work in PHP 5.6 "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'const' (T_CONST) in"

Comment: This code was tested in PHP 5.6 and works on more than one platform. Use this sandbox: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Answer (score 0):

Works only in **PHP 7**

```
<?php
    define('DAYS_OFF', array(
                    'holidays' => array(
                        'newYear' => '1 January'
                    )
                ));
    print_r(constant("DAYS_OFF"));
?>
```

Comment: @JayBlanchard the define with the array (scaler) value only works in PHP 7.

Comment: While the scalar definition only works in PHP7 you do not need the `constant()` function. You can `print_r(DAYS_OFF);`